# Change the default behavior of \\ inside cases environment?

Tags: amsmath

Based on the answer by egreg in [The curly brace is too big](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267146/the-curly-brace-is-too-big), I would like to modify the `cases` environment

After some experimentation, I found out the following option that I like the most:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\env@cases}{1.2}{0.9}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{equation*}
P^*(A) = \begin{cases} 
1 & \quad \omega_0 \in A, \\[.6ex]
0 & \quad \omega_0 \notin A.
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

My question is: how can I make `\\[.6ex]` the default behavior *inside* `cases` environment?

Comment: Related questions [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/270220) [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/417777) [3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/323383) . Some of them suggest using `dcases` environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want something else than `0.9`.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}

\subsection*{No patch, no optional argument}
\begin{equation*}
P^*(A) = \begin{cases} 
1 & \quad \omega_0 \in A, \\
0 & \quad \omega_0 \notin A.
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

\subsection*{Patch, no optional argument}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\env@cases}{1.2}{0.9}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{equation*}
P^*(A) = \begin{cases} 
1 & \quad \omega_0 \in A, \\
0 & \quad \omega_0 \notin A.
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

\subsection*{Patch, optional argument}
\begin{equation*}
P^*(A) = \begin{cases} 
1 & \quad \omega_0 \in A, \\[.6ex]
0 & \quad \omega_0 \notin A.
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

\subsection*{Different patch, no optional argument}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\env@cases}{0.9}{1.1}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{equation*}
P^*(A) = \begin{cases} 
1 & \quad \omega_0 \in A, \\
0 & \quad \omega_0 \notin A.
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

So you probably want, *before* `\begin{document}`,

```
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\env@cases}{1.2}{1.1]{}{}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Oh I was stupid:( thanks! I thought `\\[.6ex]` controls the spacing between two lines while patch effectively controls the size of the brace...